# Force two threads to access a global variable directly in memory?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I know that *volatile* in C++ does not have the same meaning as in Java, so if I'm writing a C++ application for Windows, how can I share a variable between two threads and not allowing for each thread to cache its own copy of the variable?
Does using critical sections solves this problem or does it only allows for atomicity?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, on Visual Studio, `volatile` does have pretty much the same meaning as in Java (or C#). Or at least, it used to, and still does by default; see [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd.aspx) for details.

That said, in standard C++, it is true that `volatile` means approximately nothing. Also, in standard terms, threads do not "cache" anything and your question is ill-formed. The relevant concepts are *atomicity* and *ordering*, the standard term for the latter being the "happens-before" relationship. Everything you need to design, implement, and reason about multi-threaded algorithms is captured in these concepts; the notion of "cache" has nothing to do with it.

Standard C++11 provides many mechanisms for enforcing atomicity and ordering. You will get a better answer if you ask a specific question about implementing a specific algorithm.

[Update, to clarify]

Note that I am not saying you are using the wrong terminology; I am saying you are using the wrong *concepts*.

The standard does not talk about "cached variables" using different words... It does not talk about cached variables *at all*. That is because the concept is neither necessary nor sufficient for reasoning about threads. You can know everything about caches and still be unable to analyze concurrent algorithms, and you can know nothing about caches and be able to analyze them perfectly.

Similarly, "accessing a variable directly" is not just the wrong way to talk; the very concept is *meaningless* in (standard) C++. The notion of "do it right now" means nothing when each thread is progressing at a different rate and observing state changes in a different order. In standard C++, there simply is no "access directly" or "right now"; there is only happens-before.

This is not an academic point. The wrong mental model for concurrency is almost guaranteed to lead to fuzzy thinking and sloppy, buggy code.

Your question really does have no answer as phrased. The right answer could be to use `std::atomic` or to use `std::mutex` or to use `std::atomic_thread_fence`, depending on exactly what it is you are actually trying to do. I am suggesting you ask a question that states clearly what that is.

Comment: I don't know what the correct term is, but what I meant by "cache" is that each thread read and write to its own copy of the global variable. Anyway if WinAPI does not provide any mechanism to solve this problem, I guess using volatile in VC++ is enough!

Comment: @mahmoud_t1: that depends on what you're doing.  You probably still need critical sections or some other synchronization mechanism, unless your program is only going to run on single-core systems.  And if you use critical sections you don't need `volatile`.

Comment: What I am doing is simply having two threads running, with one thread writing to a global variable and the other reading from the global variable. "And if you use critical sections you don't need volatile", so does that mean if I put the read/write code inside a critical section I can depend that the global variable will be accessed directly?

Comment: Traditionally, the compiler is indeed allowed to do things like storing a non-volatile variable in a register temporarily, or assuming that it won't be spontaneously changed from another thread.  It's not too far wrong to call that "caching".  However, critical sections are implemented using calls into Win32 API functions, and the traditional compiler has to assume that such a call might read and/or change the value of the variable.  In practice, that prevents the problem from occurring.

Comment: However, it isn't best practice, for at least two reasons: (1) in principle, a modern compiler might actually decide that it knows that EnterCriticalSection() doesn't read or modify the variable in question; and (2) it doesn't follow the modern conceptual model that the compiler is designed for.

Comment: @Nemo: I'm not trying to solve my problem in C++ but in WinAPI (if that makes any sense), I know from Java that having two threads sharing a global variable can cause two problems: 1) Each thread can "cache" its own copy of the variable and manipulate this copy from now on. 2) When editing the global variable at the same time by both threads this can result in unexpected results (I can solve this problem using critical sections in WinAPI). Now the first problem is what I don't know how to solve.